# MySQL LEFT JOIN using conditional operators (>= and <) not returning null values for the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a simple table for hotel bookings (`booking`). I'm working with MySQL.

```
booking_date    last_name   room_no     nights
2016-11-19      McDonnell   207         4
2016-11-20      Jenkins     203         5
2016-11-22      Ross        209         3
2016-11-23      Whitford    207         2
2016-11-27      Berry       207         2
```

For each day in the period `2016-11-21` to `2016-11-27`, I want to know who occupied room 207, excluding anyone who checked out that day. For example, we can see that Whitford checked out on `2016-11-25` so he should not be listed as an occupant. If there are no occupants for a given date, I want the query to return `NULL` for that date.

I created a simple calendar (`hotel_calendar`):

```
StayDate    
2016-11-21  
2016-11-22  
2016-11-23  
2016-11-24  
2016-11-25  
2016-11-26  
2016-11-27
```

I attempted to find the occupant for each day on the calendar by matching:

```
SELECT        StayDate AS 'Date',
              last_name AS 'Last Name'

FROM          hotel_calendar

LEFT JOIN     booking ON
              (StayDate >= booking_date AND   
              StayDate < booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY)

WHERE         room_no = 207 AND 
              StayDate BETWEEN '2016-11-21' AND '2016-11-27';
```

My results:

```
Date        Last Name
2016-11-21  McDonnell
2016-11-22  McDonnell
2016-11-23  Whitford
2016-11-24  Whitford
2016-11-27  Berry
```

The room is unoccupied on `2016-11-25` and `2016-11-26`. Even though I used `LEFT JOIN`, the query didn’t return the `NULL` values for those dates. Is this due to an incorrect use of conditional operators?

Comment: create a cte that will list all dates between two specified dates then left join it to your query on the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should qualify all your column names, so it is clear where they come from.  Second, never use single quotes around column aliases -- just leads to problems.

Your real issue, though, is that conditions on the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` need to go into the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.  Otherwise, the `JOIN` turns into an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.StayDate AS Date, b.last_name
FROM hotel_calendar c LEFT JOIN
     booking b
     ON c.StayDate >= b.booking_date AND   
        c.StayDate < b.booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY AND
        b.room_no = 207
WHERE c.StayDate BETWEEN '2016-11-21' AND '2016-11-27';
```